# How do I upgrade to ruby 2.0 on windows?

Tags: ruby, pik

I just installed pik into `c:\bin`. I typed in `pik list`, and it shows:

```
* 193: ruby 1.9.3p484 <2013-11-22> [i386-mingw32]
  200: ruby 2.0.0p195 <2013-05-14. [i386-mingw32].
```

I typed in: `c:\bin> pik use 200` and `c:\bin>ruby -v` and get the following error.

> 'ruby' is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

What might cause this, and how do I resolve it to properly upgrade to Ruby 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

It occurred cause RUBY is not a command that described for Windows Command Prompt.
You should first go the app you want interact with it.
For this, you should write the path of it in Command Prompt.
But I offer use Ruby Installer (http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/) that's more comfortable.
It will install all the packages are required simultaneously